# AWS Lambda migrate data from oracle db to Aurora

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I want to write aws lambda function to fetch data from on premises oracle db and migrate to aurora db.

I tried :

```
var oracledb = require('oracledb-for-lambda');
var os = require('os');
var fs = require('fs');
'use strict';

str_host = os.hostname() + ' localhost\n';

fs.appendFile(process.env.HOSTALIASES,str_host , function(err){
    if(err) throw err;  
});
```

But I am again stuck as it does not seem to work.

Can someone show me , i have table with same columns present in oracle db as well as aurora db i want to map form oracle to aurora. How to write it in java or python using aws lambda.

Answer (score 0):

The size of the library “**oracledb_for_lambda**” is more than **70 MB** which is quite high for you to compile and upload to lambda every single time. Instead of that, You can bundle the library and add it as a **lambda layer**. So that we can include the layer directly to Lambda.

Creating this bundle will be our first step. You need to create the below folder structure before adding it to the layer.

Now, In the Project folder, Create a folder named “**nodejs**” and You need to move the “**node_modules**” folder into this “**nodejs**” folder. Then, Copy the “**lib**” folder inside “**/node_modules/oracledb-for-lambda**” and paste it outside in the main project directory.

Finally, you will get a folder structure like the below image.

[image: Final folder sctructure]

That’s it, Zip the files inside the folder and Upload the Zip to S3

And you can connect using below code

```js
'use strict';
var os = require('os');
var fs = require('fs');
var oracledb = require('oracledb-for-lambda');
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    let str_host = os.hostname() + ' localhost\n';
    fs.writeFileSync(process.env.HOSTALIASES, str_host, function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
    var connAttr = {
        user: process.env.USERNAME,
        password: process.env.PASSWORD,
        connectString: process.env.CONNECTION_STRING
    };

    const promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        oracledb.getConnection(connAttr, function(err, connection) {
            if (err) {
                reject({
                    status: "ERROR"
                });
            }
            resolve({
                status: "SUCCESS"
            });
        });
    });
    return promise;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can migrate data from one or many Oracle databases using AWS DMS.
> With an Oracle database as a source, you can migrate data to any of
> the targets supported by AWS DMS.
> DMS supports the following Oracle database editions:
>
> Oracle Enterprise Edition
>
> Oracle Standard Edition
>
> Oracle Express Edition
>
> Oracle Personal Edition
>
> For self-managed Oracle databases, AWS DMS supports all Oracle
> database editions for versions 10.2 and later (for versions 10.x), 11g
> and up to 12.2, 18c, and 19c. For Amazon RDS for Oracle databases that
> AWS manages, AWS DMS supports all Oracle database editions for
> versions 11g (versions 11.2.0.4 and later) and up to 12.2, 18c, and
> 19c.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.Oracle.html